# Why are verses missing in the Psalms in my Bible?

Tags: bible, old-testament, bible-translation, psalms

Today, to my surprise, I discovered that Bible in my native Georgian language is not complete. I have checked several sources and compared to English and Russian Bibles, and there are missing verses in Psalms.  For example, Ps 109 has 31 verses but in the Georgian one it has 7 verses only.  Other chapters have similar issues, but I haven't checked other books. Why is this so?  It can't be that they could not translate them.

Comment: You should edit your post to specify which Georgian translation you are using, as there are many.

Comment: I actually discovered it in app,don't know the version,but after checked it with printed version of official Georgian church. Need to check for exact author. I am new to bible study. Now It's clear why they are different. Thanks.

Comment: I have checked with printed version of Georgian bible for authors of translation but have not found anything,It's not written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is most likely the numbering of the Psalms in your Bible.  Your Georgian translation appears to use the Greek (Septuagint) numbering that is common in Roman Catholic and Eastern Orthodox Bibles, while the Bibles you are comparing against use the numbering of the Hebrew (Masoretic) text.

Let's look at Psalm 109 as an example.  According to the Hebrew numbering,  [Psalm 109](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=psalm+109&version=ESV) has 31 verses and begins like this:

> Be not silent, O God of my praise! [ESV]

But according to the Greek numbering, [Psalm 109](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=psalm+110&version=ESV) has 7 verses and begins like this:

> The Lord says to my Lord:
>       “Sit at my right hand,
>   until I make your enemies your footstool.”

In the Hebrew numbering system, this is actually Psalm 110, as you'll see if you click the link.

Why does this happen? The short version is that some psalms are combined (or split, depending on your perspective) in the Greek version that aren't combined (or split) in the Hebrew version.  Here's the numbering breakdown, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psalms#Numbering):

```
Hebrew (Masoretic)    Greek (Septuagint or Vulgate)
    1–8                           1–8
    9–10                          9
    11–113                        10–112
    114–115                       113
    116                           114–115
    117–146                       116–145
    147                           146–147
    148–150                       148–150
```

Comment: I'm new in bible study. I have seen that in some sources they are written like (108)109 and have not notice this conformity. Thank you.

Comment: I am reading from the beginning one verse at a time,have not reached yet Ps. Just was browsing it today and stumbled upon this difference.

Comment: Glad to help! It definitely is confusing.

Comment: You should also find that you have a Psalm 151 and a number of Deuterocanonical books, such as Wisdom and Maccabees.

Comment: Wisdom and Maccabees? It's in Old or New testament?

Comment: @Sofiko You have only to check the table of contents to see :)

Comment: @Steve obviously,yes. I browsed through but in Georgian there is nothing like that. Will try other methods,investigate more.

Comment: @Steve so wisdom is wisdom of solomon and in Georgian It's translated like fables of Solomon (don't know why they did not use word "wisdom"). About Maccabee can't find yet.

Comment: @Steve They are in old testament. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuterocanonical_books